# setText() or Intent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

My app contains many activities . When user lunches it ,the app shows main activity containing a table with buttons  .If user press one of those buttons, the app will go to another activity, each button represents activity .In one of those activities the user will press button for two functions :
 1- send two string variables and one int .
 2- lunch another activity . 
In the activity , the user will edit data, after that the user will press button for two functions :
 1- send two string variables and one int to main activity (for showing it at the table) . 
2- lunch main activity .

My  problem is, one out of three variables (it's newkindm) has showed at table. I tried use more than way in sending by Intent or Bundle .

main Activity

```
         condi_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CONDIMENT.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    egg_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EGG.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    fast_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FAST.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    fish_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FISH_CHECKEN.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    fruit_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FRUIT.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    meat_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MEAT.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    milk_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MILK.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    mooca_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MOOCA.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    oil_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OIL_FAT.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    rice_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RICE_BREAD.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });

    vege_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VEGETABLE.class);
            startActivity(q);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

One of the many Activities:

```
 fas001add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent(FAST.this,Add.class);
            a.putExtra("cal", Content.Fast001.calory);
            a.putExtra("con", Content.Fast001.consist);
            a.putExtra("meal", Content.Fast001.meal);
            startActivity(a);


        }});
```

All buttons are the same

The activity what the user edit on data after that send it to main activity
here receiving:

```
    Intent n = this.getIntent();
    nam =n.getExtras().getString("meal");
    con = n.getExtras().getString("con");
    cal =n.getExtras().getInt("cal");
```

Here edit:

```
     add14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            mul= 0.25 ;
        }});
    add13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            mul=0.33 ;
        }});
    add12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            mul = 0.5;
        }});
    add1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            mul =1.0000;

        }});
    add15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            mul =1.5;
        }});
    add2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add14.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add13.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add15.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            add2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            mul=  2.000;
        }});
    beak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            lun.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            din.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            sna.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            fmeal="فطور";
        }});
    lun.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            lun.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            din.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            sna.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            fmeal ="غداء";


        }});
    din.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            lun.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            din.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            sna.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            fmeal ="عشاء";
        }});
    sna.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            lun.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            din.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybutton);
            sna.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calorybuttonplus);
            fmeal ="وجبة خفيفة ";
        }});
```

Here sending:

```
    addf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {


                   cal_mul = (double) cal;
                    cal = (int) (cal_mul * mul);
                    Intent o = new Intent(Add.this, MainActivity.class);
                   o.putExtra("kind", fmeal);
                    o.putExtra("calory",cal);
                   o.putExtra("namee", nam);
                    startActivity(o);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"الرجاء اكمال الخيارات",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }




            }});


main activity receiving (here is the problem)
                   try {
                   Intent g = this.getIntent();
            newcm =g.getExtras().getInt("calory");
            newkindm= g.getExtras().getString("kind");
            newnamem= g.getExtras().getString("namee");
            if (meal1 == false) {
                cm1 = newcm;
                kindm1 = newkindm;
                namem1 = newnamem;
                meal1 = true;
                sumf = sumf + cm1;
                kindmu1.setText(kindm1);
                calmu1.setText(cm1);
                summanu.setText(sumf);
                namemu11.setText(namem1);

            }
            if (meal1 == true & meal2 == false) {
                meal2 = true;
                cm2 = newcm;
                kindm2 = newkindm;
                namem2 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal2 == true & meal3 == false) {
                meal3 = true;
                cm3 = newcm;
                kindm3 = newkindm;
                namem3 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal3 == true & meal4 == false) {
                meal4 = true;
                cm4 = newcm;
                kindm4 = newkindm;
                namem4 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal4 == true & meal5 == false) {
                meal5 = true;
                cm5 = newcm;
                kindm5 = newkindm;
                namem5 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal5 == true & meal6 == false) {
                meal6 = true;
                cm6 = newcm;
                kindm6 = newkindm;
                namem6 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal6 == true & meal7 == false) {
                meal7 = true;
                cm7 = newcm;
                kindm7 = newkindm;
                namem7 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal7 == true & meal8 == false) {
                meal8 = true;
                cm8 = newcm;
                kindm8 = newkindm;
                namem8 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal8 == true & meal9 == false) {
                meal9 = true;
                cm9 = newcm;
                kindm9 = newkindm;
                namem9 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal9 == true & meal10 == false) {
                meal10 = true;
                cm10 = newcm;
                kindm10 = newkindm;
                namem10 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal10 == true & meal11 == false) {
                meal11 = true;
                cm11 = newcm;
                kindm11 = newkindm;
                namem11 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal11 == true & meal12 == false) {
                meal12 = true;
                cm12 = newcm;
                kindm12 = newkindm;
                namem12 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal12 == true & meal13 == false) {
                meal13 = true;
                cm13 = newcm;
                kindm13 = newkindm;
                namem13 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal13 == true & meal14 == false) {
                meal14 = true;
                cm14 = newcm;
                kindm14 = newkindm;
                namem14 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal14 == true & meal15 == false) {
                meal15 = true;
                cm15 = newcm;
                kindm15 = newkindm;
                namem15 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal15 == true & meal16 == false) {
                meal16 = true;
                cm16 = newcm;
                kindm16 = newkindm;
                namem16 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal16 == true & meal17 == false) {
                meal17 = true;
                cm17 = newcm;
                kindm17 = newkindm;
                namem17 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal17 == true & meal18 == false) {
                meal18 = true;
                cm18 = newcm;
                kindm18 = newkindm;
                namem18 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }
            if (meal18 == true & meal19 == false) {
                meal19 = true;
                cm19 = newcm;
                kindm19 = newkindm;
                namem19 = newkindm;
                sumf = sumf + newcm;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

errors
[logcat error only](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzuKJZPSkhCaS0RvR3ZwODVUeWs)

Comment: Post your Errors, post your `LogCat`, and improved format code.

Comment: @Aspicas I upload logcat.txt       what do you recommend me ?

Comment: File not accessible show error log properly

Answer (score 1):

It seems error like dlopen failed: 
If the library you want to dlopen is not in the standard search path you have a number of options:

Specify the full path to the file in dlopen

dlopen("/full/path/to/libfile.so");
Add the path to the library via LD_LIBRARY_PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library/ ./executable
use the ld -rpath option to add a library path to the application.

g++ -link stuff- -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library/
Note that options 1 & 3 hardcode the library path into your application. -rpath does have an option to specify a relative path, i.e.

-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/../lib/
Will embed a relative path into the application.

Try it.